# Elasticsearch multiple fields search (AND OR)

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to figure out Elasticsearch.
I looked all over the internet and all I found was basic examples.

First I need to search in two fields (field_A, field_B) and to return results where

- field_A has the value equal to valueA or valueB or valueC
- AND
- field_B has the value equal to valueD

I manage to do that like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "field_A": [
                  "valueA",
                  "valueB",
                  "valueC"
                ]
              }
            }
          ],
          "should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "field_B": "valueD"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I need to search in three fields (exact match)

- (field_A = valueA  AND  field_B = valueB  AND  field_C = valueC) OR (field_A = valueA1  AND  field_B = valueB1    AND  field_C = valueC1) OR ...

Or something like this:

- field_A = valueA  AND  ( (field_B = valueB    AND  field_C = valueC) OR (field_B = valueB1 AND field_C = valueC1) OR ... )

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use boolean(and / or ) filters of elasticsearch.

Here is a simple use-case for your first requirement, you can model the filters for your other requirement.

```
POST /_search 
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "or": {
               "filters": [
                  {
                     "and": {
                        "filters": [
                           {
                              "term": {
                                 "fieldA": "value_a"
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "term": {
                                 "fieldB": "value_b"
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "term": {
                                 "fieldC": "value_c"
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "and": {
                        "filters": [
                           {
                              "term": {
                                 "fieldA": "value_a1"
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "term": {
                                 "fieldB": "value_b1"
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "term": {
                                 "fieldC": "value_c1"
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

For your type of requirement using and filter and or filter seems good, but always prefer bool filter (as you did) if you can use that.

References;

[And Filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-and-filter.html)

[Or Filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-or-filter.html)

Hope this helps!! Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason why should he always prefer to use a bool filter instead of using and/or filter?

Comment: Boolean filter use Bitsets for document to mark if filter is matched or not (and it is cached) which have huge performance impact , And/Or filter don't (they go by filtering document to document). The article will make more clear concept. http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/all-about-elasticsearch-filter-bitsets/

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information! I thought that and/or filter used bitsets too.